# merge specific line using awk and sed

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, command

I want to merge specific line

Input :

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE
AAA
BBB
DDD
CCC
EEE
```

Output Should be

```
AAA
BBB
CCC DDD
EEE
AAA
BBB
DDD
CCC EEE
```

I want to search CCC and merge next line with it.

I have tried with awk command but didn't get success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use awk patterns, if the line matches `/CCC/` then print the line with a space at the end and go on to the next line. Otherwise (`1`), print the line.

```
awk '/CCC/ { printf("%s ", $0); next } 1' file
```

Comment: One more question i want to store the output in same file i don't want to use awk ... > newfile

Comment: Then sed with -i option like `sed -i '/CCC/ { N; s/\n/ / }' file`

Answer (score 1):

Using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed '/CCC/ { N; s/\n/ / }' file
```

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '{ ORS=(/CCC/ ? FS : RS) }1' file
```